# Saving tab content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, rss

I am working on a website where I have to save a tab which has RSS feeds in it and retrieve it later when the user returns( I am using Boostrap).
The html code for tab is

```
<!-- RSS FEED jquery plugin -->
<script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js"></script>

<!--Adding tab Header-->
        <ul id="pageTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#page1" data-toggle="tab">Welcome</a></li>
        </ul>
<!--Adding tab Content-->
       <div id="pageTabContent" class="tab-content">
           <div class="tab-pane active" id="page1">
                <p>--- RSS FEED--- </p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function () {
$('#page1').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
                         limit: 5
                          });
                      });
        </script>           
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want to save the layout and the url so I can retrieve it back. I tried

```
function saveLayout()
{
    //Save content to database 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveLayout.php",
        data: {
                    tab_header:$('#pageTab').html(),
                    tab_content:$('#pageTabContent').html()
             },
            success: function(data1) 
            {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data1);
            }
      }); 
}
```

But this doesn't work, the javascript for RSS feed fills the div with the fetched html and I dont think its wise to store all the content
because if the user logs out and logs in again, this will fetch him the old RSS feeds from the database.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript to fetch the rss really doesn't need to be in the html div that receives its content.
You could just put it anywhere else in your code, and then only fetch the content that it fetched with the exact same 'saveLayout()' function you are using now, as it won't be copying that javascript uselessly, or will it be refetching the rss everytime, for that mather.

```
<div class = "tabContainer" id="tabContainer0" >
    <!-- RSS FEED jquery plugin -->
    <script src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function () {
                      $('#page1').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', 
                              {
                                   limit: 5
                              });
                          });
     </script>

    <!--Adding tab Header-->
            <ul id="pageTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#page1" data-toggle="tab">Welcome</a></li>
            </ul>
        <!--Adding tab Content-->
           <div id="pageTabContent" class="tab-content">
               <div class="tab-pane active" id="page1">
                    <p>--- RSS FEED--- </p>                       
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually the URL is generated dynamically. User can create multiple tabs, each page with different RSS URL.(I didn't want to make the question complex). Hence the RSS script is placed within the html div(There is a function that creates this html div dynamically)

Comment: There is no doubt that the tabs can be subdivised in divs without the javascript to fetch the rss being in the content div. edited the code a (very) little bit to show the gen idea